# K-Means Clustering using parameters library suddenly not showing results. Cluster_analysis() , predict(), plot()

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I was working on a dataset and performing some k-means clustering. I was using the parameters library and the following commands which ran super smoothly until it just stopped giving me results.

The cluster_analysis() command gives the output but predict() gives only NAs and plot gives the error
"Error in UseMethod("principal_components") : no applicable method for 'principal_components' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')""

The code is shown below. I have attached the data as well along with the sample plot that i used to get when the code ran without errors.

Can someone please help?

```
library(parameters)

res_kmeans <- cluster_analysis(PC12,
                               n = 4,
                               method = "kmeans")
predict(res_kmeans)
plot(res_kmeans)
```

[**The output I used to get when the code ran properly**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z3BD.png)

[**The Data can be found here**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jQ924N79s7HHvCk9M95e3wgO9WgfnscX/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102553514056934220929&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem although my plot is very different from the plot you show. I downloaded your data as "PC12.xls - Sheet1.csv" and used `read.csv()` to import it into R. Everything ran fine. You did not show how you imported the data. What does `str(PC12` show?

Comment: Thankyou so much for commenting on my problem and trying to solve it

So this PC12 is obtained by the PCA of 29 initial variables. The eigen value for only 8 components was above 1 so I am only considering these 8 PCs for my K-means cluster analysis. I make a new variable for the 8 PCs as PC12. The steps i follow are
`PC12 <- All_pca$x`
`PC12 <-PC12[1:594,1:8]`

This is the output I get for str(PC12) is:
`str(PC12)
num [1:594, 1:8] -2.596 3.319 1.207 1.662 -0.686 
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  $ : chr [1:594] "1" "2" "3" "4" 
  $ : chr [1:8] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" `

Comment: These are the initial commands I ran:

'All' is the data with all the 29 initial variables before PCA

`All_pca <- prcomp(All, scale = TRUE)

fviz_eig(All_pca, addlabels = TRUE, ylim = c(0, 30), ncp=15)

eig.val <- get_eigenvalue(All_pca)
eig.val

str(All_pca)
summary(All_pca)
All_pca$x



PC12 <- All_pca$x
PC12 <-PC12[1:594,1:8]
PC12`

Answer (score 1):

Your `PC12` object is a matrix. The manual page of the `cluster_analysis()` function indicates that it requires a data frame. I downloaded your .csv file and used `read.csv()` to import it and that produces a data frame so it ran fine for me. The `cluster_analysis()` function does not produce a warning or error matrix when given a matrix, but it returns NAs for the cluster memberships (`attr(res_kmeans, "clusters")`). The quick solution is to use

```
res_kmeans <- cluster_analysis(as.data.frame(PC12), n = 4, method = "kmeans")
```

in your code. You could also contact the package maintainer (`maintainer("parameters")` to get the email address). It would be simple to check the first argument and convert it to a data frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. I tried the fix you provide me to get rid of the NAs but the total variance explained by the 4 clusters dipped to 20.63% from 84.88% when compared with the non data frame code.